# Falconframework app not running with gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, falconframework

I have this trivial falcon app :

```
import falcon

class ThingsResource:
    def on_get(self, req, resq) :
        #"""Handels GET requests"""
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
                resp.body = '{"message":"hello"}'


app = falcon.API()
things = ThingsResource()
app.add_route('/things', things)
```

I'm trying run it using gunicorn this way :

```
arif@ubuntu:~/dialer_api$ gunicorn things:app
```

But when i get this when i try to connect it with `httpie` :

```
arif@ubuntu:~$ http localhost:8000/things
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Length: 141
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>Internal Server Error</p></h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is so trivial, i don't what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 7th line, is indented when it shouldn't be.
Your 6th line refers to resq, instead of resp which you use later.
Which means your later lines which refer to resp fail.

Whenever you have Internal Server Errors like this, it's often because of faulty code. Your gunicorn process should have been spitting out errors. I've attached a corrected version of your code, including making sure it fits with python's conventions (4 spaces per indent, for instance). Tools like [online python code checker](http://pych.atomidata.com/), can help you with small snippets of code like this, especially issues with spacing.

```
import falcon


class ThingsResource():
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = '{"message":"hello"}'


app = falcon.API()
things = ThingsResource()
app.add_route('/things', things)
```

Save this code into another file, and run diff to see what I've changed. The main issue was the resp and the inappropriate indentation.